# Animation script not working in browsers other than Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a script which changes the background color of some items when hovering it. This works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox and MS Edge (other browsers I've tested).

Why is that?

Script:

```
var oldfeatureitem = '';
$(document).delegate('div.wrap-feature-item', 'mouseenter',( function(){
 oldfeatureitem = $(this).clone();
 var ele = $(this).find('div.front').find('div')[0];
 var kleur = ($(ele).css('border-color'));
 $(this).find('div.feature-item').css('background-color', kleur);
  $(this).find('div.front').css('background-color', kleur);
 $(this).css('background-color', kleur);
 $(ele).css('background-color', kleur);
 $(this).find('div.back').css('background-color', kleur);
}));

$(document).delegate('div.wrap-feature-item', 'mouseleave',(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith(oldfeatureitem);
}));
```

Html structure:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp pad-5" data-wow-duration="2s" >
    <div class="wrap-feature-item">
        <div class="feature-item">
        <a href="diensten/strategie.html">
            <div class="front face ">
                <div class="strategie_ico"><i class="icon-lamp"class="ico"></i></div>
                <div class="title">Strategie</div>
            </div>
        </a>

            <div class="back face center">
                <div class="ico strategie_ico"><i class="icon-lamp"></i></div>
                <div class="title">Strategie</div>
                <div class="text">
                     Lorem ipsumm
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS as well? At the glance, it seems strategie_ico class CSS properties are not accessible in FF.

Comment: I think I got the answer for you. Other than Chrome, var kleur = ($(ele).css('border-color')); returns nothing and therefore not changing the background using kleur later on.

Comment: @Rahi Why does it return nothing in other browsers than Chrome?

Comment: See my answer below. Also, accept my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than Chrome, `var kleur = ($(ele).css('border-color'));` returns nothing and therefore not changing the background using `kleur` later on.

Chrome support `border-color` property but with other browsers you have to be specific like below.

```
$(ele).css("border-top-color");
$(ele).css("border-right-color");
```

See the updated code below.

```js
var oldfeatureitem = '';
$(document).delegate('div.wrap-feature-item', 'mouseenter',( function(){
 oldfeatureitem = $(this).clone();
 var ele = $(this).find('div.front').find('div')[0];
 var kleur = ($(ele).css('border-top-color'));
  console.log(kleur);
 $(this).find('div.feature-item').css('background-color', kleur);
  $(this).find('div.front').css('background-color', kleur);
 $(this).css('background-color', kleur);
 $(ele).css('background-color', kleur);
 $(this).find('div.back').css('background-color', kleur);
}));

$(document).delegate('div.wrap-feature-item', 'mouseleave',(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith(oldfeatureitem);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Html structure:

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp pad-5" data-wow-duration="2s" >
    <div class="wrap-feature-item">
        <div class="feature-item">
        <a href="diensten/strategie.html">
            <div class="front face ">
                <div class="strategie_ico"><i class="icon-lamp"class="ico"></i></div>
                <div class="title">Strategie</div>
            </div>
        </a>

            <div class="back face center">
                <div class="ico strategie_ico"><i class="icon-lamp"></i></div>
                <div class="title">Strategie</div>
                <div class="text">
                     Lorem ipsumm
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: border-top-color are valid in MS Edge/IE. Have you tried encapsulating whole JS script in $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Comment: It is inside one @rahi

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that in google chrome the value of

```
var kleur = $(ele).css('border-colour');
```

is rgb(51, 122, 183) while in other browsers the value is returned as empty.

it should be empty in chrome to because if you console.log() the element $(ele) it has no border-colour or if you check it at style properties of the element.

if you want a specific colour give it to the kleur variable. and it will work.
So the reason that your code doesn't work is that the variable in other browsers except google chrome has an empty value.

Comment: Why is it returning empty in all browsers except Chrome?

Comment: to what i saw by the console the attribute was not defined in either chrome or other browsers. it must be a chrome bug but i'm not really sure.